# R programming: Trying to expand a column based on unique values

Tags: r, dataframe, organization

I'm working with R studio.
I'm having issues with how to divide this up
I have:

| ID | COLOR | NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 321 | RED | 3 |
| 321 | GREEN | 10 |
| 321 | BLUE | 4 |
| 067 | RED | 50 |
| 067 | BLUE | 2 |
| 067 | YELLOW | 3 |
| 111 | PURPLE | 10 |
| 111 | YELLOW | 2 |

I want:

| ID | red | green | blue | yellow | PURPLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 321 | 3 | 10 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 067 | 50 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 111 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 10 |

I got the advice on here to use:

```
Data <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(cbind(file_name[1], unlist(file_name[-1]))))
```

and I got a good start, but I had to change my data around and I can't incorporate the extra number column I added.

Comment: May be you can look at fonction dcast ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_wider`.

```
library(tidyr) # install.packages("tidyr") if required
df1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = COLOR, 
              values_from = NUMBER, 
              values_fill = 0)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
     ID   RED GREEN  BLUE YELLOW PURPLE
  <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
1   321     3    10     4      0      0
2    67    50     0     2      3      0
3   111     0     0     0      2     10
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(321L, 321L, 321L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 111L, 111L), 
                      COLOR = c("RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "RED", 
                                "BLUE","YELLOW", "PURPLE", "YELLOW"), 
                      NUMBER = c(3L, 10L, 4L, 50L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 2L)), 
                      class = "data.frame", 
                      row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Im getting the following error: Error in `pivot_wider_spec()`:
! Can't convert `fill` <double> to <list>.

Comment: Code works using the example data in your question. If that isn't accurate, please edit it. [It's better to use dput than tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can see the structure of the data.

Comment: I got it when I removed values_fill. I got NULL values but I can replace those later if they cause problems